# Flask-Session session not saving inside a Flask-SocketIO websocket request

Tags: python, flask, flask-socketio, flask-session

I am using Flask-Session with Flask-SocketIO, but when I try to save my session from inside a websocket, it does not store, even though I am using server side session storage. I am redirecting the user directly after the session is stored.

```py
session['li'] = True
session['id'] = account['id']
session.modified = True
```

Flask 2.2.2
Flask-Session 0.4.0
Flask-SocketIO 5.3.0

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found a solution by adding a random key-value pair to the session when the login page was opened.

Comment: can you explain little bit?

Comment: Basically, while loading the page where the socket connection would start, I just set session['x'] = 'y' to create the session manually.